# Passing one list instead of two in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

Here I have written a function which takes two lists as argument. But when I called this function passing one list as argument, it works well! Why is this working? Here name_function has two arguments but I passed only one list as argument.

```
def name_function(names=list(),_list=list()):
    for name in names:
        _list.append(name)
    return _list
print(name_function(['mike','smith','bob']))
```

Comment: If you pass only a single list, then the second list is automatically set to an empty list per: `_list=list()`.

Comment: Because you have default arguments.

Comment: `names=list()` means that you are creating empty list and passing it to name parameter as default value. Same thing done  with _list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @L3viathan I think OP is asking why default arguments work in the first place. But with mutable defaults, I'm sure that question will be relevant soon enough. ;)

Comment: @dibery yes I have now got this. When two lists are arguments, after passing one list , the later would be default one.

Answer (score 0):

- Here in the function definition you have initialized both the
  arguments with the empty list i.e. you are using two default
  arguments in the function definition.
- For the above reason the function call works if you provide provide
  both the arguments or any one of the arguments or no argument at
  all.
- To learn more about default arguments in python you can refer [this
  link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/) or [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_default_parameter.asp).